# Add Font Awesome Embed CDN Script To WordPress

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, cdn

This is my original code that pulled Font Awesome icons, which is placed in my functions.php file:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-font-awesome', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), '4.6.1' );
```

They've recently started offering unique embed codes that appear like so:

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/##########.js"></script>
```

But I'm not sure how to use this with wp_enqueue_style.

Comment: You'll have to use `wp_enqueue_script`, but it is similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full snippet would be this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'prefix-font-awesome', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/##########.js' );
```

Comment: Why did you use 'wp_enqueue_script' instead of 'wp_enqueue_style' for CSS?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson Because it's not css but javascript.

Comment: Is it have any difference on using **https://** rather than **//address** ?